# Include 0 in a COUNT() in Hive

Tags: hive, count

I have a table of users and medications and want to return the count of all meds by user even if the count is 0. The result would have columns for user, med, and count, and 9 users x 9 meds = 81 key rows.

```
    user = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

    med = ['acyclovir' ,'azathioprine' ,'basiliximab' ,'bevacizumab' ,'carboplatin','ciprofloxacin_dexamethasone_otic' ,'cisplatin' ,'clofarabine', 'cyclophosphamide']
```

I tried:

```
SELECT user, med, COUNT(*) 
FROM db.table
WHERE user IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
AND med IN ('acyclovir' ,'azathioprine' ,'basiliximab' ,'bevacizumab' ,'carboplatin','ciprofloxacin_dexamethasone_otic' ,'cisplatin' ,'clofarabine','cyclophosphamide') 
GROUP BY user, med 
ORDER BY user ASC
```

However, this only returned count for meds by user with COUNT(*) > 0. How can I change it to return all counts?

Comment: Are user med diff table? Or same table different columns of array type? Can you try removing filter on med column.

Comment: Same table different columns. User is an integer and med is string. I am searching a table of med observations to find if any of the meds listed were given to the users, and if so how many times. If the count is 0 I have to include that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need to get a count of med given to a user, if none, then show 0.
Here is the qry you can use.

```
SELECT user, 
SUM(case when med IN ('acyclovir' ,'azathioprine' ,'basiliximab' ,'bevacizumab' ,'carboplatin','ciprofloxacin_dexamethasone_otic' ,'cisplatin' ,'clofarabine','cyclophosphamide') then 1 else 0 end ) as med_count
--this will give you count of medicine taken by user. If 0 then the count will be 0. But its difficult to show the name of medicine.
FROM db.table
WHERE user IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9') 
GROUP BY user 
ORDER BY user ASC
```

Edit : could you please try this sql. It will give you med count of an user. If med isnt in the list it will show 0.

```
SELECT user, 
SUM(case when med IN ('acyclovir' ,'azathioprine' ,'basiliximab' ,'bevacizumab' ,'carboplatin','ciprofloxacin_dexamethasone_otic' ,'cisplatin' ,'clofarabine','cyclophosphamide') then 1 else 0 end ) as med_count,
--this will give you count of medicine taken by user. If not in listed med then the count will be 0. 
case when med IN ('acyclovir' ,'azathioprine' ,'basiliximab' ,'bevacizumab' ,'carboplatin','ciprofloxacin_dexamethasone_otic' ,'cisplatin' ,'clofarabine','cyclophosphamide') then med else null end as med
FROM db.table
WHERE user IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9') 
GROUP BY user ,case when med IN ('acyclovir' ,'azathioprine' ,'basiliximab' ,'bevacizumab' ,'carboplatin','ciprofloxacin_dexamethasone_otic' ,'cisplatin' ,'clofarabine','cyclophosphamide') then med else null end 
ORDER BY user ASC
```

Comment: I tried your query, while adding med to the select statement before the sum, and to the group statement, but it pulled in counts for meds that are not in my list

Comment: Thats why you dont add med to the list. You can add a where clause like your sql and remove med from select.

Comment: Okay. I removed med and retried the query. It gave an aggregate count for each user, but did not differentiate by med. I am aiming to have something like:

| user | med | count |
|    1   | acyclovir | 5  |
| 1 | azathioprine | 8 |
[including all meds and counts]
| 1 | cyclophosphamide | 0 |
| 2 | acyclovir | 0 |
[including all meds and counts]
| 2 | cyclophosphamide | 4 |
| 3 | acyclovir | 7 |
[including all meds and counts]
| 3 | cyclophosphamide | 0 |